# gvisGeoMap() - how to zoom into Ontario

Tags: google-maps, data-visualization, google-visualization

Does any know how to look at a specific province in Canada (Ontario) using gvisGeoMap() from googleVis package?  I've tried to set the 'region' option to "CA-ON" which is the ISO 3166-2 code for the province but it doesn't work.  The zoom option doesn't quite apply either.  Looking for some suggestion.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can plot data by Canadian provinces with a Geo Map.
It appears to me that Google pushes and develops the Geo Chart more than the Geo Map.
The Geo Chart uses SVG / VML to render the chart rather than Flash.

On December 6 Google published a new version of their Visualisation API.
The Geo Chart was improved as well, see:
http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart.html

The new version (0.2.13) of the googleVis package takes those updates into account.
In partticular, you can set the resolution of the geo chart, e.g. to 'provinces':
I believe the best you can achieve today for Canadian provinces is the following

```
library(googleVis)
plot(gvisGeoChart(CityPopularity, locationvar="City", colorvar="Popularity",
     options=list(displayMode="markers", region="CA", resolution="provinces")))

# There seem to be more granular maps available for the US:

plot(gvisGeoChart(CityPopularity, locationvar="City", colorvar="Popularity",
    options=list(displayMode="markers", region="US", resolution="metros")))

plot(gvisGeoChart(CityPopularity, locationvar="City", colorvar="Popularity",
    options=list(displayMode="markers", region="US-AL", resolution="metros")))
```

I hope this helps.